# Cant get cart to work using external javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to put together this basic cart using external javascript. It works perfectly in jsBin but when I try to run through a browser it wont work. I am guessing it is my html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[here is my jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ufanep/133/edit)

Comment: Please define "won't work."  What is the behavior you are expecting, and what is the behavior you are seeing?  Are there specific error messages?  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, why are you making a cart using Javascript?

Comment: sorry. its for school so it is purely for learning. The problem i am having is when I try to run my cart.html on firefox I only see my add to cart button. Is it my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the jsBin is executed at the end of the `<body>`, which means all elements are accessible. Make your code is executed (which accesses specific DOM elements) **after** they are rendered/ready. A normal way to do this is to put your code in `window.onload`, or do what jsBin does and put your JavaScript at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: @user2300240 Haha no problem. It's not something I would've thought jsBin did, but when I inspected the page with Firebug, I found that's what's happening. This is why I like using jsFiddle - it lets you define where your Javascript code goes